# Convert SID string to varbinary(85)

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, uuid

My ssrs server was moved to a different domain because of which the `Users` table need to be updated with new `SID`

current sid:

```
S-1-5-21-39949945-591092532-1226208319-1007
```

I want to convert this sid into varbinary(85) which would look something like this:

```
0x0105000000000005150000005AE2326D3D9AC66DD5CCABEE56040000
```

I had earlier found a link but unable to find it now.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try the undocumented `SID_BINARY` built in function

```sql
SELECT SID_BINARY('S-1-5-21-39949945-591092532-1226208319-1007');

--Results in: 0x01050000000000051500000079966102345B3B233F741649EF030000
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the builtin `CONVERT` function with SQL Server Management Studio.

```
select CONVERT(VARBINARY,'S-1-5-21-39949945-591092532-1226208319-1007') FROM TableName
```